# Windows Runtime app Encrypt sqlite database and synchronization

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, encryption, windows-runtime

I'm writing an app that can synchronize sqlite databases in different devices e.g. Windows 8 device and Windows Phone 8 device.

Now for synchronization I'm using azure mobile services back end, but there is no encryption right now, so the data at local storage of device, and on azure stored as "open".

The question is really stupid:

How to get the same encryption/decryption keys on different devices?

I can see the following solutions, but they seem to have drawbacks:

1. Generate them from password? - I think that is a bad idea.
2. Generate the key on server? - but there is a scenario when user doesn't use synchronization at all, so he may not be connected to internet.

Comment: Please take a bit more time writing the question, a spelling checker should be generally available. Try and write things as they should be im -> I am. Don't make it harder on us than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask user for some password/account information and encrypt/decrypt database file on the fly with key that will be generated from the user submitted data. There is no information about the user that you can use to encrypt/decrypt file on different devices. Maybe only [name/email from the signed Microsoft account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659737.aspx) can be used to generate the encryption/decryption key, but it's not strong at all.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.
So what if i will do such way - at the first start of an app user creates a password, that will not be as his Microsoft account password. 
Then i genereate the key based on this password, and use it to encrypt/decrypt file. 
Then user synchronizes his DB with the server (authentication via Microsoft account)
Then he get another device, and synchronize db from server to his new device, and to ecrypt/decrypt this db user uses his password (that was created at first start of the app)
?

Comment: Exactly. I see no other way to protect the data.

Comment: So there are antoher small question. 
When i decrypt data, how can i programmaticaly define that user use correct password?

Comment: Additional file/field is required for this task. You should hash the password with something like PBKDF2 and store it with database. You can even transform password hash to sting (Base64) and use it as database filename. Correct password - file found, not correct - not found.